# chai expect passing when returned value is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai

It seems to me that this test should not be passing

**chai test**

```
const chai = require('chai')
const expect = chai.expect;
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const request = chaiHttp.expect;
const config = require('../../app/config');
const worker = require('../../app/worker');

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('server response', function () {
    .....

    it('should return 200', function () {
        chai.request(`http://localhost:${config.port}`)
        .get('/')
        .end(function (err, res) {
            expect('as').to.have.status(200);
        });
    });
});
```

**Terminal**

```
> NODE_ENV=test mocha --timeout 20000 --recursive test/ --compilers js:babel-core/register



  server response
    ✓ should return 200


  1 passing (150ms)
```

Comment: Should not be passing because?

Comment: `'as'` is clearly not having a statue of 200 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your are missing the `done` callback. Try like this

```
it('should return 200', function (done) {
    chai.request(`http://localhost:${config.port}`)
    .get('/')
    .end(function (err, res) {
        expect('as').to.have.status(200);
        done();
    });
});
```

With this code, the test will only pass if

```
expect('as').to.have.status(200);
```

is true (which will always be false with your current example)